# Update the index.html file of the main container in initContainer

Tags: kubernetes

I have a container image that already has the `index.html` file. My goal is to pick that `index.html` update it (using simple placeholder replacement) and then put it back.

I am trying to use the `initContainer` for the same. But somehow it's not working out for me.

Here is what I have tried in `deployment.yaml`

```
 initContainers:
        - name: init-container
          image: "my-image-name"
          command: ["/bin/sh", "-c"]
          args:
            - cp /usr/share/nginx/html/index.html /tmp/index.html
            - sed -i 's#<base href="./">#<base href="/my-base/">#' /tmp/index.html
            - cp /tmp/index.html /usr/share/nginx/html/index.html
          volumeMounts:
          - name: custom-index
            mountPath: /usr/share/nginx/html/

containers:
        - name: {{ .Chart.Name }}
          securityContext:
            {{- toYaml .Values.securityContext | nindent 12 }}
          image: "my-image-name"
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: 8080
              protocol: TCP
          volumeMounts:
          - mountPath: /usr/share/nginx/html/
            name: custom-index

volumes:
        - emptyDir: {}
          name: custom-index
```

However with above, I am getting the following error:

```
Error: failed to create containerd task: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: error during container init: error mounting "/var/lib/kubelet/pods/bb343f44-00eb-477b-9e26-17949a73100d/volume-subpaths/custom-index/my-container-name/7" to rootfs at "/usr/share/nginx/html/": mount /var/lib/kubelet/pods/bb343f44-00eb-477b-9e26-17949a73100d/volume-subpaths/custom-index/my-container-name/7:/usr/share/nginx/html/ (via /proc/self/fd/6), flags: 0x5000: not a directory: unknown
```

How to achieve this?

Please note that I cannot maintain the separate copy of `index.html`, I need to use the one present in the main container, update it and put it back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For initcontainer can you please check with below. If required correct the sed statement

```
 command: ["/bin/sh", "-c", "cp /usr/share/nginx/html/index.html /remoteDir && sed -i 's#<base href=\"./\">#<base href=\"/my-base/\">#' /remoteDir/index.html"]
 volumeMounts:
 - name: custom-index
   mountPath: /remoteDir
```

Comment: How this is different than the one mentioned in the comment?

Comment: Args array syntax with space will be an issue. Refined copy of modified file and no need to copy back modified file in remote directory

Comment: I think I am able to proceed further with your input. But is there any way I can continue to use the array syntax as I have to do multiple operations. Also, I didn't get the point of "no need to copy back the modified files". Then how can I tell my nginx container to use the modified file as index.html ?

Comment: the path "/remoteDir/index.html" is the same volume / path  which will be getting attached in the main container after initContainer process is completed.  Once its copied to remoteDir during init process that will be enough as the same being referred in main container.

Comment: Thank you Nataraj for the pointers. I am above to move ahead. Appreciate your help